# Circular arrow in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

How do I draw a circular arrow (to indicate commutativity) in tikz-cd, similar to the one in the middle of the following diagram?

[image]

(Image from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43395/ways-to-indicate-commutativity-and-non-commutativity-of-a-diagram-when-using-xym).)

Comment: Related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495457/arrows-inside-a-commutative-diagram-using-tikzcd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use of PDFlatex or XeLaTeX with $\circlearrowleft$ from `amssymbol/amsmath` with scalable size.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd, arrow style=tikz,diagrams={>= latex}}


\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm,column sep=2cm,inner sep=1ex]
\bar A  \arrow[thick,swap] {d}{\bar F_q}
&
\bar A_E   \arrow[thick,swap]{l}[name=U]{\pi^\star}
\arrow[thick]{d}{\bar F_{q,E}}
\\
\bar A     & \bar A_E     \arrow[thick]{l}[name=D]{\pi^\star}  
\arrow[to path={(U) node[midway,scale=3] {$\circlearrowleft$}  (D)}]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [> Minimal working example <](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484486/38074). I had to spend a few minutes figuring out the exact syntax for naming arrows and also separating the actual solution from the OP-provided code. Feel free to integrate my MWE into your answer, so that the actual solution is more prominent.

Answer (score 7):

You can draw an arc using the option `->` following the syntax described in the [documentation](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) in the *Arc Path Reconstruction*.

> \draw (starting point x, starting point y) arc (starting angle:ending angle:radius);`

For instance this code will produce an arrow like the one requested

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm,gray!50,very thin] (-1.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,5.9);
  \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\bf{x axis}};
  \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\bf{y axis}};
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\mathbf{\x}$};
  \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\mathbf{\y}$};
  \draw[thick, ->] (3,2) arc (0:270:1cm);% syntax (starting point coordinates) arc (starting angle:ending angle:radius)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At least an explanation of how to include this into `tikz-cd` would be great.

Answer (score 3):

MWE from [Jesse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188665/38074):

[image: Square diagram with nodes A, B, C, D and circular arrow in the center.]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        % The syntax for naming arrows is as follows
        %     \arrow[...options...]{...direction(s)...}[name=...name...]{...label...}
        % If you want no label:
        %     \arrow[...options...]{...direction(s)...}[name=...name...]{}
        A \arrow[]{d}{a-c} \arrow[]{r}[name=a-b]{a-b} & B \arrow[]{d}{b-d}\\
        C \arrow[]{r}[name=c-d]{c-d} & D
        \arrow[to path={(c-d) node[midway,scale=1] {$\circlearrowleft$} (a-b)}]{}
    \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use Lua- or XeLaTeX:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=5pt, column sep=5pt]
\overbar{A} \arrow[swap, "\overbar{F}_q"]{dd} &  &  \overbar{A}_E    
\arrow["\overbar{F}_{q,E}"]{dd} \arrow[swap, "\pi^\ast"]{ll}  \\
 & \cwopencirclearrow & \\
\overbar{A} & &  \overbar{A}_E \arrow["\pi^\ast"]{ll}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

a variation of accepted answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\tikzset{C/.style={circle, minimum size=8mm,
                   node contents={},
                   append after command={\pgfextra{%
        \draw[-{Straight Barb[flex']}](\tikzlastnode.150) arc (150:450:4mm);}
                }}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=12mm,
arrow style=tikz,
arrows=semithick,
diagrams={>={Straight Barb}}
                ]
\bar{A}_E \dar["\bar{F}_q" ']
        & \bar{A}_E \dar["\bar{F}_{q,E}"]
                    \lar["\pi^\star" ',""name=U]      \\
\bar{A} & \bar{A}_E \lar["\pi^\star"  ,""name=D]
                     \ar[to path={(U) node[pos=.5,C] (D)}]{}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

*differences*: common style for arrows, used shorter (alternative) syntax for `\arrows`, different way for defining arrows names, defined TikZ picture for inner circled arrow.

[image]