# Arrows inside a commutative diagram using tikzcd

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[dd, "p"'] \arrow[ddrr, phantom, "\Rightarrow"] \arrow[rr, "q"] &  & B \arrow[dd, "r"] \\
 &  &  \\
 C \arrow[rr, "s"] &  & D
 \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[dd, "p"'] \arrow[rrdd, "q"]    &  & \\
&  &                                                  \\
B \arrow[rr, "r"] &  & C                                         
\end{tikzcd}

 \end{document}
```

This is what I have written to get a commutative diagram.

I want to add an arrow (\Rightarrow) inside the diagram from bottom left corner to top right corner. Can some one help me to do this? I have tried to add using "phantom" but it is not coming as I expected. I want this pointing from top left corner to bottom right corner (or bottom left corner to top right corner).

Comment: Just add `\arrow[ddrr]` after `A`. But why doubling the number of rows and columns?

Comment: No No.  I do not want from A to D. I want this arrow to be "inside" the diagram.. I do not know how to clarify this.. I want to draw a  commutative diagram. Some symbol showing this is commutative diagram @egreg

Comment: `\arrow[uurr]` rightafter `C`, then. Or insert `\circlearrowleft` in the centre of the diagram.

Comment: “All diagrams in this paper are understood to be commutative, unless the contrary is explicitly stated for a particular diagram”.

Comment: @egreg that is definitely one option :) I am planning to do in diagram also :) Please see the edit..

Comment: @Bernard Please see the edit. I think I did not say clearly before..

Comment: From top left corner to bottom right, or from bottom left to top right corner?

Comment: @Bernard anything is ok.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `shorten` a `Rightarrow` as you like.

For the triangle, you can name the label and draw an arrow to it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{row sep/normal=50pt, column sep/normal=50pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A\arrow[d, "p"']\arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=25pt, shorten <=25pt, dr]\arrow[r, "q"] &  B\arrow[d, "r"]\\
    C\arrow[r, "s", swap] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A\arrow[d, "p"']\arrow[r, "q"] &  B\arrow[d, "r"]\\
    C\arrow[r, "s", swap]\arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=25pt, shorten <=25pt, ur] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A\arrow[d, "p"']\arrow[rd, "q"{name=M}] \\
    B\arrow[r, "r", swap]\arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, to=M] & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am realising the beauty.. This makes so much sense.. If I write " \arrow[Rightarrow, ur]", it will give arrow **from C to B**... If I do not want to **start** from C, I should just decrease the length of the arrow  :D :D, how do I do that? by writing " \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=30pt, shorten <=30pt, ur]" :D :D Thanks...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, it's very simple :)

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply this, to specify the diagram commutes? Unrelated: I took the liberty to simplify your code, in particular  removing unnecessary packages (already loaded by another package).

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = large, column sep = large]
 A \arrow[d, "p"'] \arrow[r, "q"] & B \arrow[d, "r"] \\
 C \arrow[ur, phantom, "\scalebox{1.5}{$\circlearrowleft$}" description]\arrow[r, "s"] & D
 \end{tikzcd}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have combined your answer with other answer and got what I wanted..  :)

Comment: I have added the answer.. If you think it can be made better, please feel free to edit :)

Comment: I am having trouble doing the something for triangle.. I have added in the question.. can you please see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a phantom arrow, with the label in the middle via `description` and `sloped`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
A \arrow[dr,phantom,"\to" description, sloped]
  \arrow[d, "p"'] \arrow[r, "q"] & B \arrow[d, "r"] \\
C \arrow[r, "s"] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have combined your answer with other answer and got what I wanted..  :)

Comment: I have added the answer.. If you think it can be made better, please feel free to edit :)

Comment: I am having trouble doing the something for triangle..  I have added in the question.. can you please see..

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[dd, "p"'] 
\arrow[rr, "q"] &  & B \arrow[dd, "r"] \\
&  &  \\
C \arrow[rr, "s"] \arrow[uurr, phantom, "\scalebox{2}{$\Rightarrow$}" description, sloped] &  & D
\end{tikzcd}.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here there are two version using `xy` package. The first mode has the classic tips (see the example below),

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\RLongrightarrow}{\rotatebox{45}{$\Longrightarrow$}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{\ar @{} [dr] |{\RLongrightarrow}
A \ar[d] \ar[r] & B \ar[d] \\
C \ar[r] & D}
\end{document}
```

the second has the same tips of `tikz-cd` where I have forgotten, before, to add the labels. See the code below and the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\RLongrightarrow}{\rotatebox{45}{$\Longrightarrow$}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{\ar @{} [dr] |{\RLongrightarrow}
A \ar[d]_p \ar[r]^q & B \ar[d]^r \\
C \ar[r]_s & D}
\end{document}
```