# Arrows inside a diagram using tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I would like to draw the following diagram using tikzcd.

[image]

I have asked a question before to draw arrows inside a square and a triangle. It is at [Arrows inside a commutative diagram using tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495457/arrows-inside-a-commutative-diagram-using-tikzcd)

I have tried to “imitate” the idea there but it is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

The working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
x \arrow[rr, "f", swap, bend left=49] \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, to=M]
\arrow[rr, "h"', bend right=49] \arrow[rr, "g"{name=M}] &  & y
\end{tikzcd}


 \end{document}
```

Comment: I have also tried to do this for two arrows $f,g$ instead of $3$ arrows $f,g,h$. That is also not working..

Answer (score 4):

Here is one. Next time, please make sure your example is minimal, most of those packages are irrelevant. For this I've just adapted the example in the tikz-cd manual. Note that you of course cannot refer to the name of a node before it has been defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  x
  \arrow[rr, "f"{name=F}, bend left=60]
  \arrow[rr, "\mathclap{h}"{name=H,pos=0.52}, bend right=60]
  \arrow[rr,"g"{name=G}]
  &  & y
  \arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=G]
  \arrow[Rightarrow, from=G, to=H,yshift=-1pt]
\end{tikzcd}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. :) :) I will be careful next time

Comment: Can you suggest some place where I can find hints of how to draw these? I am trying a slight variation and itis not working... I am trying to take $x,y,z$ and 4 arrows; 2 from x to y and 2 from y to z... I am trying to imitate this idea...

Comment: Since I don't know what they should look like, no.

Comment: I did not mean the example I asked in the comment.. In general, Is there a guide to draw these kind of diagrams?

Comment: You draw them on paper first, then start at one end. That is what I normally do. Then I ask for help if I get stuck

Comment: Ok. sure.......

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I came up with my own code for some other type of diagram. Thanks to your words..