Commutative diagram (two squares and diagonal arrow) and loops in the commutative diagram
I would like to write the following diagram,

I've now created the upper right triangle, but I am continuing to draw the entire diagram along with two loops in the commutative diagram.
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{amsthm}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }




\usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}

 \begin{document}
        \[
        \begin{tikzcd} A\ar[r, "j"]\ar[dr, "\phi", swap ]&B\ar[d,"f", hook']\\ &&&D
        \end{tikzcd}
        \]
    \end{document}

Thank you very much for your help.

Please try to compile your posted code … and upgrade it as needed. Thank you

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Thank you for your comments. I modified my question.

I removed some preamble which is not needed to write my diagram.

@BrauerManinobstruction, you still load a lot of package which are unrelated to your problem. And document example is still not compilable. Please, be so kind and test your document example before you publish it here. BTW, code for communicative diagram is poorly related to your problem, For starting point see my answer (and others too) to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188650/circular-arrow-in-tikz-cd.

You could do something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
    execute at end picture={
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[scale=2] {$\circlearrowleft$} (mycd-3-2);
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[yscale=3.2, xscale=-1.5, rotate=90, yshift=-.1em] {\textasciitilde} (mycd-3-1);
      }
    ] 
    A\ar[r, "j"]\ar[dr, "\phi", swap ]\ar[d,"\circlearrowright"]&B\ar[d,"f", hook']\\ 
    C\ar[r]\ar[dash, d, "j", swap, shift left=.2em, outer sep=.3em]&D\\
    E\ar[r]&F\ar[u, "f", hook, swap]
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


